# Creating small low quality audio files with arecord

Tags: linux, audio

On linux (ubuntu) I want to record basically as low a quality and small audio file I can for some long recordings. So long as the audio is discernable and not so bad it's irritating to listen to (scratchy or something) I want to make it as small as possible.

It seems like the -f parameter controls this, and there are a number of formats listed, however I can't find any documentation on what they really represent as far as quality.

Does anyone know the proper flag(s) for this? I might add I don't really care if it's arecord or rec, or some other sound recording app. So long as it's recording audio from my browser, like arecord does, that works.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Short description:

- S/U Signed or unsinged format (You'll go with signed)
- 8/16/24/32 number of bits per sample (8 should do)
- BE/LE Big endian or little endian

for speech S8 would be ok, with 1 channel `-c1` and `-r22050` sample rate.

Your soundcard won't be able to output all formats, so you'll have to check.

Answer (score 0):

*arecord* will output a .wav file. That is fixed bitrate uncompressed audio. The worst case if file size matters.

If you want to reduce the size of the file then the only solution you get with *arecord* is to lower the number of bits per sample and the sampling frequency as shown in @stoney's answer.

---

I suggest you use [*ffmpeg*](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Audio-Options) instead which will enable you to encode the audio on the fly at a variable bitrate and therefore enabling much better quality/filesize ratios :
See, in particular in the doc linked hereabove how to :

- Set the audio quality (codec-specific, VBR) with the -aq parameter
- Set the audio codec with the -acodec parameter

Comment: thanks i found something like this:
 
ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 2 -i default -acodec libmp3lame -ab 8k audio.mp3

works, and as near as i can tell is about as small as i can get